# difference between command line option -cp and -classpath?

Tags: java, classpath

I am not able to run a Apple.class file without specifying command line `cp` option. I have a Apple.class file in my E:\ directory. but when I run E:\java Apple, It show me error on command prompt like `"Could not load or find a main method"`.

what is the difference between `-cp` and `-classpath`?

Comment: no difference between -cp and -classpath

Comment: You have two different questions here - what are you asking? `-cp` and `-classpath` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

`-cp` and `-classpath` are the same option. You just need to specify the fully-qualified name (e.g. `com.mypackage.Apple`) and also include all the required classes/jars + the main class into the classpath.

Comment: Thanks Eng.Fouad for providing the solution.